# inline divs fill width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a fancy header. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y1xp1nsL/) for you to see how it looks like before I explain my issue.

This header is great in medium/big screen width, but the problem comes at smaller screen width, where the text does not fit in that width and gets overlapped by the right div.

Here is the html/css(same as JSFIddle). Below I will explain what I want to achieve

html:

```
 <div class="header">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <span>TITLE</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
div.header{
  height:30px;
  font-size:30px;
  width:100%;
  margin-top:100px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
div.header .left{
  background-color: #D82B38;
  width:10%;
  height:30px;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  border-radius:0 15px 0 0;
}
div.header .text{
  width:20%;
  display: inline-block;
  height:30px;
  float:left;
}
div.header .right{
  background-color: #D82B38;
  width:70%;
  height:30px;
  display: inline-block;
  float:right;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 15px;
}
div.header .text span{
  font-size:30px;
  color: #D82B38;
  position: relative;
  top:-5px;
  text-align:center;
  display: block;
  font-weight:500;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}
```

I would like to give some left and right paddings to `div.text`, and make it's width depend on the size of the text, and then `div.left` and `div.right` takes their width depending on the remaining width of the screen(always being the left one a lot smaller than the right one), instead of always having the same percentage. I know I could play with media queries to change that percentage in smaller screens, but I know media queries does not work well in internet explorer and I prefer to avoid them.

I tried several things using CSS to get this, but I can't get it to work. Please tell me if my question is quite unclear and I will try to clarify what I mean.

Thanks in advance!

EIDT: I do not want to use javascript for this, I know there must be some way to achieve it using purely CSS

Comment: Don't mix `inline-block` with `float`, because float breaks the inline-block (it transforms to `block`) or inline elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
  flex: 1 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.flex-item-fixed {
  -webkit-flex: 0 70px;
  flex: 0 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item-fixed1 {
  -webkit-flex: 0 10%;
  flex: 0 10%;
}

.left {
  background-color: #D82B38;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0 15px 0 0;
  height: 30px;
}

.right {
  background-color: #D82B38;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 15px;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/y1xp1nsL/2/)**

Comment: This one is great! I have never used flexbox before, but this seems to work very fine. Still, there is no support for IE, but I guess I will have no option than work on some  fallback for it. F*ck explorer I hate it

Comment: It works with 10, 11 , you only need prefix - http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox  On the new microsoft browser (Edge) it´s working with no know issues

Comment: So, in the lines that are `-webkit-*` I duplicate them with prefix `-ms` and it should work in IE10+ ? I'm about to accept this answer, it works great

Comment: That should work...test it. Don´t forget if does do not work perfectly just use old (2012) flexbox syntax

Comment: It's not working well in Safari. The left and right divs resize as I resize the window, but the one that contains the text is being assigned a smaller width than it's actually has, which makes the right div overlap it. Any idea?

Comment: It works if I delete `.flex-item-fixed` `flex: 0 70px` and `webkit-flex: 0 70px` property. But I am a noob at flexbox, is it ok if I delete it or it might cause any trouble ?

Comment: Instead of using complete rule, use separate rules ex:  flex-direction: nowrap; Check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 2):

Flexible widths (percentages) are the key to responsive web design, but in some cases, this is not the way to go. In this case in particular, you want to keep the right side of the header responsive meanwhile the left side, including the text, is static. That avoids any flickering and movement, as well as excess @media queries. You can keep the responsiveness by employing the calc function.

Here is what I did. I gave the left side and the text a 350px width shared between the two. (100px and 250px). 350px is well within the width of any smartphone. And I told the right side to make it 100% - 350px. That makes the right side respect the left side and adjust accordingly.

SCSS/LESS - If you were using LESS or SCSS/SASS you will have a real winner here, because you can store these two fixed widths in variables and then if you ever needed to change these values, LESS or SCSS/SASS would adjust everything for you.

Here is your new CSS:

```
div.header{
  height:30px;
  font-size:30px;
  width:100%;
  margin-top:100px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
div.header .left{
  background-color: #D82B38;
  width:150px;
  height:30px;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  border-radius:0 15px 0 0;
}
div.header .text{
  width:200px;
  display: inline-block;
  height:30px;
  float:left;
}
div.header .right{
  background-color: #D82B38;
  width: calc(100% - 350px);
  height:30px;
  display: inline-block;
  float:right;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 15px;
}
div.header .text span{
  font-size:30px;
  color: #D82B38;
  position: relative;
  top:-5px;
  text-align:center;
  display: block;
  font-weight:500;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}
```

And here is how it looks like in a [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/rxRjbG)

**EDIT**

As an alternative option, you can distribute the widths and use media queries to re-adjust. This is something you will be able to use in older browsers. To center the text accordingly, you have 2 options, 1. is depicted in my DEMO after I edited it. using position left and transform. And if that gives you problems with older browsers, option 2 is to wrap the text is another div and center align its content. See the DEMO again for the alternative option

Comment: I liked this answer. Problem is, in smaller screens I would like left div to still be smaller than right div. But i guess I could use media queries for that one, and iexplorer users can s**ck it up. Let me try and test it and I will give you the accepted answer. Anyways, calc function is still unsupported for iexplorer 8 and 9. Is there any possible fallback? (Even if it does not look exactly how it should, but at least something)

Comment: Read my comment about LESS/SCSS. That will take care of the calc problem. You can do the calculation in the SCSS and it will do it for you. On the other hand, why are you developing for such old browsers? Anyone using those browsers would expect design issues since most of the world already stopped supporting those browsers.

Comment: On a second note, you can make it multi browser, if you reaaaaaaaly had to support IE 8 and IE9. I'll edit my answer with that

Comment: I would like to mark both as accepted answers because this was very good too, but my designer preferred flexbox instead of fixed width on left div. Still, thanks a lot for your time and dedication!

Answer (score 0):

This one works from IE8 but uses `flex` if it's supported by the browser.

```css
div.header{
  display: table;
  height:30px;
  font-size:30px;
  width:100%;
  margin-top:100px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
div.header .left{
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #D82B38;
  width:10%;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:0 15px 0 0;
}
div.header .text{
  display: table-cell;
  width:20%;
  height:30px;
}
div.header .right{
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #D82B38;
  width:70%;
  height:30px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 15px;
}
div.header .text span{
  font-size:30px;
  color: #D82B38;
  position: relative;
  top:-5px;
  text-align:center;
  display: block;
  font-weight:500;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}

@supports (display: flex) {

  div.header{
    display: flex;
  }
  div.header .left{
    display: block;
  }
  div.header .text{
    display: block;
    min-width: 90px;
  }
  div.header .right{
    display: block;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <span>TITLE</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
```